# magento2 redirect from observer to custom controller

Tags: magento2, redirect

Admin login success observer redirect to my custom controller

```
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

    //print_r($observer);
     $message = 'entered custom method';
    $this->_logger->info($message);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

    // Your code

    $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect($this->_response, 'sample/test/index'));
    return $resultRedirect;
```

Comment: To which event did you write the observer?

Answer (score 4):

### USE OF DIE() AND exit on magento 2 is not good for code standard

You can do this  some code.

add `__construct()` function at **your  Observer class**.

and on this `__construct()` function **inject two classes**

- `\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory`
- `\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url`

Then using s`etRedirect($url)->sendResponse()` redirect to your custom controller

**Your class can be:**

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
             $event = $observer->getEvent();
             $RedirectUrl= $this->_url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($RedirectUrl)->sendResponse();
         die();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry it redirects to dashboard

Comment: @Amit Bera sir,how to redirect to product page using product url from observer $productUrl = $currentProduct->getProductUrl();

Comment: from where you want to redirect and also on which event you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Can't use the **die() method** because of **magento coding standard** so i prefer below solution.

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_url;
    public function __construct(
        ......

        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
        ......
    ) {

        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;

    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
             $event = $observer->getEvent();
             $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
             $this->_redirect->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl);

    }
}
```